# InvalidOperationException while trying bulkInsert the datatable into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I got data from text file into datatable and now when I am trying to insert that data into a SQL Server 2008 database, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: String or binary data would be truncated

I cannot get the source of error ie which record is throwing this error.

The code is as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 159)
    {
    }
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName,DestTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
}

bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TxtFileInfo";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
```

I have the datatable in the `dt` variable. And matched columns for both datatable created from text file and also the empty table created in database to add the values to it.

I have copied all records from text file into datatable using below code.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
      int count1 = reader.FieldCount;

      for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
      {
          string value = reader[i].ToString();                            
          list.Add(value);
      }

      dt.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());
      list.Clear();
}
```

I have got proper records from the text file. Also the number of columns are equal. My database table `TextToTable` has all columns of datatype `nvarchar(50)` and I am fetching each record as string from text file. But during bulk insert the error shown is

> Cannot convert string to nvarchar(50)

Comment: Share you Table strucutre....seems you are trying to insert data which has less length in DB (for example: you have data length 20 but in DB accept only 10 )

Comment: In my table every column has datatype of nvarchar(50).

Comment: Then check data which is coming from text file. Have if condition to check length of data in your code and have break point to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Prathyush Yes I have some data that is longer than 50 characters. What is the solution for this problem.. Do I need to change the database table datatypes or what..

Comment: Nope, just increase the length of column in DB or if no business impact then trim your data and save it. Call is yours

Comment: Well, you have two separate errors here, the last of which doesn't make sense to me. However, go ahead and try to insert this into a temp table which has the same DDL as your regular table, except make the columns NVARCHAR(4000) and see if you still get truncation. If not, your data is longer than 50. Also, you may have some new line / CR hidden values (CHAR 13 and CHAR10) in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to insert data which has less length in DB (for example: you have data length 20 but in DB accept only 10 )

To check data which is coming from text file. Have if condition to check length of data in your code and have break point to troubleshoot.

If yes then increase the length of column in DB.

```
alter tablename
alter column columnname varchar(xxx)
```